# Spring Tool Suite build error with Spring Boot 2 and JDK 10

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I've a Spring Boot 2.x application. I'm using STS 4.

My application is compiled with JDK 8, but when I switch to JDK 10 Eclipse enters into a build loop as shown in the pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I see a generic `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the details. I created a new workspace to avoid any other problem.
Coming back to JDK 8 the project is built and runs correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you pom.xml is build with Java 10.

If it doesn't work try to build a new app with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and selecting Java 10. Like the image.

[Spring Initializr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jIE4.png)

Comment: My pom.xml is built with Java 10. I checkit out with the Spring Initializr and it is similar. Of course I've the <java.version>10</java.version> tag.